# psycopg2 copy_to part of table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

there is a copy_to to copy table data into file like:

```py
cursor.copy_to(fp, 'table_name')
```

but I don't need to copy all table data, just a part of it.
So when I do:

```py
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.copy_to(fp, 'table_name')
```

it still copies the whole table.
Is there a way to copy data from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cursor.copy_expert()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert), place your query as an argument to `COPY` command, e.g.:

```
sql = """
    copy (
        select * 
        from my_table 
        where id < 5 
        order by id
    ) to stdout
"""

with open('/data/my_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    cursor.copy_expert(sql, fp)
```

Read also about [Postgres COPY command.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Comment: is there any way to copy table structure to file? DDL of table

Comment: Yes, you can get the whole definition of a table from [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html), especially querying pg_class, pg_attribute and pg_constraint but there is no ready-to-use tool for that. In psycopg2 you can get information on columns of a query result from [cursor.description.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description)

Comment: I can not use regular copy, as I don't have superuser privileges. Any idea? The only idea, which I have, is via a temp table.